# Copy First Line On Text File Once It Is Open Then Copy Second Line Once It Is Open Again

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Example:

Text Line in Sample.txt

```
Red
Black
Yellow
```

Opening Sample.txt Copy First Text Line Only

Result:

```
Red
```

Opening Sample.txt Again Copy Second Text Line Only

Result:

```
Black
```

Opening Sample.txt Again Copy Third Text Line Only

Result:

```
Yellow
```

I Need A Batch File Or Vbscript Thanks

Comment: Copy the lines where?

Comment: "once it's open"? Please try to explain better what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple function that uses [OpenTextFile](https://OpenTextFile) and [ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/readline-method) to return the desired line from a file:

```
Function GetLineFromFile(sFileName, iLineNumber)

    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFile
    Dim iLineCounter
    Dim sLine
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, True)
    
    iLineCounter = 0
    sLine = ""
    
    Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = objFile.ReadLine
        iLineCounter = iLineCounter + 1
        If iLineCounter = iLineNumber Then Exit Do
    Loop

    GetLineFromFile = sLine
    
End Function
```

Then you use a [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loop from 1 to 3:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim sFileName
    Dim iCounter
    
    sFileName = "C:\Temp\file1.txt"
    
    For iCounter = 1 To 3
        MsgBox GetLineFromFile(sFileName, iCounter)
    Next

End Sub
```